# How to return in UITableView fixed row height or dynamic row height according to a certain condition?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a tableView where I need  to return a fixed row height in some cases, but a dynamic height that takes the size of the content of a label.
How could I achieve both cases for same tableView.
Because when I implement

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return 75
    }
```

The height is always fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to do that first of all you need to set the label’s number of lines to zero.
Then give the label constraints to the tableView cell from for edges. (I assume you already did and this is not the main problem).

Then in your viewDidLoad add:

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
```

and implement heightForRow function as follows:

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       if condition == true {
       return 200 
      //This will return fixed height
       }

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your delegate height method like this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   if indexPath.row  = 1 || indexPath.row  = 4 || indexPath.row  = 6{// your required cells index
   return 75 

   }
  else{
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the number of lines of your label to 0.

Also implement heightForRow and estimatedHeightForRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if yourRequiredCondition {
         return requiredHeight
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if yourRequiredCondition {
         return requiredHeight
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're on the right track. Override the **heightForRowAtIndexPath** of UITableView's datasource method, Something like below.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSString *labelString = @"Your cell text, probably you should have an array accessed through indexPath";
     CGSize defaultSize = CGSizeMake(yourLabel.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);

     //Get the height of the label, based on the text.
     CGFloat textHeight =
     [labelString boundingRectWithSize:defaultSize
                            options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                         attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[yourfont]}
                            context:nil].size.height;

     // Now the textHeight will have the height of your label, 
     // based on your text for each cell.
     // While returning you can return the textHeight + constant height.
     // Constant height, is nothing but other static elements of cell's
     // Aggregated height & spaces.

     return textHeight+CONSTANT_HEIGHT;
}
```